# If $u_n$ are uniformly bounded in $L^\infty$, $u_n \to u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, is $u$ also bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain.

Let $u_n \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ with $|u_n|_{L^\infty} \leq M$. If $u_n \to u$ in $L^2$, is also $u \in L^\infty$?

We know that for a.a $x$, $u_n(x)$ is bounded uniformly in $n$. Does it not follow that $u(x)$ is also bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows indeed, because there is a subsequence $(u_{n_k})_k$ such that $u_{n_k}(x) \rightarrow u(x)$ almost everywhere, i.e. for all $x \in X\setminus N$, where $N$ is of measure zero (that is a standard result on Lebesgue spaces).

Let $N_n \subset X$ be a null-set with $|u_n(x)| \leq \Vert u_n \Vert_\infty \leq M$ for all $x \in X\setminus N_n$.

Conclude $|u(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in X\setminus (N \cup \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{N} N_n})$, i.e. $|u(x)| \leq M$ a.e.